Are there examples of sects other than Vishnuism denigrating DEVOTEES of Vishnu?
All sects denigrate the deities of other sects at the very least to establish the supremacy of their own sectarian deity.  The logical principle called "Nahi Ninda Nyaya" is cited - the denigration is not real denigration but is simply intended to show the supremacy of the deity who is held to be better.
But here is a quote from Sanatana Goswami

One should not hear anything about Kṛṣṇa from a non-Vaiṣṇava. Milk touched by the lips of a serpent has poisonous effects; similarly, talks about Kṛṣṇa given by a non-Vaiṣṇava are also poisonous (Quoted by Sanatana Goswami from the Padma Purana).

The Padma Purana citation is most likely a fabrication - but this Goswami is equating non-devotees of Vishnu to poisonous snakes!!
But are there examples of sects other than Vishnuism denigrating devotees of Vishnu?

In the Devibhagavata Purana, while praising the Gayatri & sandhyavandana, it is stated that lapse in the worship of Vishnu & Shiva aren't as heinous as the lapse of sandhyavandana for a brahmana. In the following chapters, it describes Tantrika texts like Pancharatra & Shaivagama to be created for those brahmana who were cursed to be born as heretics devoid of sraddha in Veda by Gautama (in revenge of them falsely framing him for gohatya). This may sound like a subtle denigration of Shaiva & Vaishnava viewpoints, but not as harsh as the one you cited.

Take a look at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61147/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-pancharatra @অনু  The exceptional status of Vishnuism when it comes to denigration of other sects is quite clear.

And regarding the comment of Sanatana Goswami, you should take the context into account. At this time, Bengal had been ruled by Muslims for about 3 centuries. With their priviledges tax-free lands donated by the Hindu kings taken away, Bengali brahmana society had taken extreme measures  to isolate themselves from Muslims in face of persecution, notably by resorting to hyper-orthodoxy. This manifested most notably in geneological record-keeping. Vaishnavism in Bengal had always been mostly adhered by the middle & lower castes, with most of the upper-castes & brahmanas observed Shaktism.

Writing before the Islamic conquest, Bengali poet Chandidasa's Krishnakirtana also discussed Radha-Krishna lila (similar to Jayadeva doing it in Sanskrit) but his composition was considered rather crude (& pornographic, according to British era commentators) compared to the same events described by Jayadeva & 14th century Maithili scholar Vidyapati. And the worship of local deities was also very popular with the Bengali masses. Gaudiya Vaishnavas faced to task of popularising the spiritual meaning of apparently erotic events & create a philosophy centered on it, & to make people accept it too.

NOTHING justifies how vital Vishnuist sectarianism is TODAY, now that all other sectarianisms have largely disappeared @অনু


Who says other sectarianisms have disappeared ? I remember seeing while being in  Quora, a Shakta person stating that Madhvacharya was the incarnation of the pig that had been killed by Bhagavana Shiva in the Kirata-Arjuna lila. 2) Vaishnavas being in majority will obviously mean that Vaishnava zealotry will be more visible than others. This is pure case of probability.


you are comparing stray unorganized ants to a giant organized elephant @অনু  Prabhupada wanted to align monotheist Vishnuism with semitic monotheism saying that Krishna is the same as Christa..  Thankfully that movement has petered out, for now.  Your "both sides"ing this case is totally invalid.

and the fundamental specious sophistry of claiming "all deities refer to Vishnu" going all the way to Rig Veda is so aesthetically jarring @অনু
